# Wait for asynchronous callback result

Tags: .net, silverlight, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am performing an http web request which asynchronously gets a response from the server. I wish to perform actions on the result directly and do not wish to have any code running in the meanwhile. The reason it has to be asynchronous is that I am writing a silverlight application.

Here is a code snippet

```
{
....

request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Callback), request);

//Some UI Code to be done after the callback 
}

private void Callback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
//Code needed to be done before the UI code 
}
```

But as soon as it reaches the async request it skips the callback and return to the calling function.

Is there any way to be able to wait for the asynchronous request. I have tried using WaitOne() on the asynchronous result but it did not solve the problem.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the question really that you just want to stop user interaction while waiting for the response? That is the most common situation with Silverlight.

Comment: Yes that is what I want... After the request is sent, the next thing i want to do is use the result of the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
IAsyncResult ar = request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(Callback), request);
ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(5000);
```

In this particular case I am using the timed out version of `WaitOne()` which returns true if the wait was successful. You could use any of the `WaitOne()` overloads though.

Comment: It still gives the same result. It never comes back to callback function. It just continues with the statements in the calling function.